# UI Kit - Trigger Scrollspy programmatically many times

Tags: javascript, uikit

I want to fire `Scrollspy Event` during a click event, but the event is just fired at the first time as you can see in snippet bellow.

```js
let fires = 0;

setInterval(() => {
 UIkit.scrollspy('h1', { cls: 'uk-animation-fade' });
  
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = ++fires;
}, 500)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.9/css/uikit-core-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.9/js/uikit-core.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hi, I want to fade in many times, but I can't</hi>
<h2>Fade in event should be fired <span>0</span> times</h2>
```

The example is simple and just to show what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I found a way to do what I looking for.

```js
let fires = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].className='';
  setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].className='uk-animation-fade';
      }, 500)
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = ++fires;
}, 1000)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.9/css/uikit-core-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.9/js/uikit-core.min.js"></script>

<h1 class='uk-animation-fade'>Hi, I want to fade in many times, but I can't</hi>
<h2>Fade in event should be fired <span>0</span> times</h2>
```